# Can't deliver email inside Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, actionmailer, resque

I have this `Resque` background job:

```
class InvestmentNotification
  @queue = :investment_email

  def self.perform(investment, investors)
    puts "Notify about #{investment['name']}"
    investors.each do |investor|
      puts "Notify #{investor['name']}"
      mailer = InvestmentMailer.notify_about_updates(investment, investor)
      puts 'Mailer set up'
      mailer.deliver_now
      puts 'Mail delivered'
    end
    puts 'Delivered all emails'
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I enqueue job, everything goes fine until `mailer.deliver_now`. `deliver_now` just does nothing and blocks the whole queue. `puts 'Mail delivered'` - this code is never executed.

How can I fix this issue and send email inside `Resque`?

Comment: are you sure your mail settings are correct in your `production.rb`? I would recommend doing a test where you can call `mailer.delivery` via console to ensure the settings are correct.

Comment: It says `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `delivery' for #<ActionMailer::MessageDelivery:0x000000037c4450>`

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I fixed it. It seems that I had a syntax error in template, however the exception wasn't raised and `deliver_now` was executing forever.

Comment: Did you have an exception notifier configured for resque? Without it exceptions won't be raised as expected.